# Bluetooth intermittently disconnects

Tags: debian, gnome, bluetooth

I'm using a Dell XPS13 laptop running `Linux debian 4.19.0-9-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.118-2+deb10u1 (2020-06-07) x86_64 GNU/Linux`. Every so often my bluetooth stops working and I have to restart my computer to fix it.

Running `sudo hciconfig hci0 reset` produces: `Can't init device hci0: Connection timed out (110)`

`hciconfig -a` output:

```
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 9C:B6:D0:8C:C6:42  ACL MTU: 1024:8  SCO MTU: 50:8
    DOWN 
    RX bytes:16038619 acl:914914 sco:0 events:16294 errors:0
    TX bytes:29114 acl:183 sco:0 commands:3232 errors:0
    Features: 0xff 0xfe 0x8f 0xfe 0xd8 0x3f 0x5b 0x87
    Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
    Link policy: RSWITCH HOLD SNIFF 
    Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT
```

This is my `lsusb; sudo rfkill list` output:

```
Bus 004 Device 004: ID 0bda:8153 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8153 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 0424:5807 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 2109:0820 VIA Labs, Inc. 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 2109:8888 VIA Labs, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 008: ID 03f0:0667 HP, Inc 
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 03f0:0269 HP, Inc 
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 046d:0892 Logitech, Inc. OrbiCam
Bus 003 Device 005: ID b58e:0005 Blue Microphones 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0424:2807 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 2109:2820 VIA Labs, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0489:e0a2 Foxconn / Hon Hai 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:58f4 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Here is my `dmesg` output:

```
[199822.744526] Bluetooth: hci0: setting interface failed (32)
[199824.609972] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x200c tx timeout
[199826.629956] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0401 tx timeout
[199830.675115] Bluetooth: hci0: setting interface failed (32)
[199832.577943] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x2005 tx timeout
[199834.593891] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x200b tx timeout
[199834.753788] Bluetooth: hci0: setting interface failed (32)
[199836.609853] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x200c tx timeout
[199838.625852] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0401 tx timeout
[199842.678915] Bluetooth: hci0: setting interface failed (32)
[199844.577771] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x2005 tx timeout
[199846.593753] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x200b tx timeout
[199846.744753] Bluetooth: hci0: setting interface failed (32)
[199848.609746] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x200c tx timeout
[199850.625697] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0401 tx timeout
```

And my `sudo systemctl status bluetooth` output:

```
Aug 03 18:06:39 debian bluetoothd[24758]: RFCOMM server failed for :1.260/Profile/HSPHSProfile/00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb: rfcomm_
Aug 03 18:06:41 debian bluetoothd[24758]: Loading LTKs timed out for hci0
Aug 03 18:06:49 debian bluetoothd[24758]: Failed to set mode: Failed (0x03)
Aug 03 18:44:01 debian bluetoothd[24758]: Failed to set mode: Failed (0x03)
```

Any help would be appreciated, this is a really annoying problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 23):

I also have these intermittent connection issues with the bluetooth. I use the following commands to get it working without have to reboot:

```
hciconfig hci0 down
rmmod btusb
modprobe btusb
hciconfig hci0 up
```

I hope this helps you !

Comment: I appreciate the reply, unfortunately I still get `Can't init device hci0: Connection timed out (110)` from this :(

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 21.04 with rtl8821c

Comment: I did these steps, but when I do the final: "hciconfig hci0 up" I get: "Can't get device info: No such device". Any ideas?

Comment: This works for me on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: @vhessel Did you find this to work permanently or does the issue come back after a bit?

Comment: Thanks! This works for me on Linux Mint 20.3 Una 64-bit (Kernel Linux 5.13.0-27-generic x86_64).

Comment: remeber to use sudo and before the above run 'sudo rfkill unblock all'

Answer (score -3):

I was having this problem when connecting to any bluetooth device, refreshed the OS about 30 minutes ago and no disconnects since.